# diagonalizability and finding a basis for $\mathbb R^3$

Tags: matrices

My question is about matrices:

let $T$ be a linear operator on the vector space $\mathbb R^3$ which is represented in the standard basis by the matrix

$$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        -9 & 4 & 4 \\
        -8 & 3 & 4 \\
        -16 & 8 & 7 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

I need to prove that $T$ is diagonalizable and I need to find a basis for $\mathbb R^3$ each vector of which is a characteristic for $T$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You want to find the eigen-values of $T$, so you solve
   $$
   \begin{vmatrix}
   -9-\lambda & 4 & 4 \\
   -8 & 3-\lambda & 4 \\
   -16 & 8 & 7-\lambda
   \end{vmatrix}
   $$
   When you simplify this, you get
   $$
   (\lambda+1)^2(\lambda - 3)
   $$
   and so the eigen-values of $T$ are $\{-1,3\}$
2. To find eigen-vectors associated to the eigen-value $-1$, you try to find a vector $(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ such that
   $$
   \begin{pmatrix}
   -8 & 4 & 4 \\
   -8 & 4 & 4 \\
   -16 & 8 & 8
   \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
   x_1 \\
   x_2 \\ x_3
   \end{pmatrix} = 0
   $$
   If you think about it long enough, you will see that
   $$
   (1,1,1) \text{ and } (1,2,0)
   $$
   are both linearly independent solutions, and hence eigen-vectors.
3. Now do the same for the eigen-value $3$, and you will get a third non-zero vector $(x_1,x_2,x_3)$. Now check that the set $\{(1,1,1),(1,2,0), (x_1,x_2,x_3)\}$ forms a basis for $\mathbb{R}^3$ and write down the matrix of $T$ w.r.t. this basis.

Comment: If the OP "thinks enough" ? (S)He needs to do some maths there, say to solve a homogeneous system.

Comment: @DonAntonio : I don't understand what you are saying - could you expand on it?

Comment: @P  Where you wrote "If you think about it long enough, you will see that..." is unusual, or perhaps even irrelevant. Thinking *a lot* about this won't help if one doesn't know how to solve homogeneous linear systems. That's what I meant. Of course, one can *think enough* and **check** that the vectors you give indeed are lin. ind. solutions, but that begs the question: how did you get them?

Comment: Well, it is quite obvious that I meant that OP needs to solve the system - if one writes everything with the strictest math-nazis in mind, then things would get boring rather quickly wouldn't it?

Comment: No need of strictest math-nazi things, whatever that may mean to you. Just to *try* to be more accurate, precise and clear. Of course, we **all** should try to be more accurate, precise and clear.

Comment: @P and @D IMHO you both gave way too much help.  Since juliet's question is highly presumed to be homework you nearly completely solved that task ...

Comment: There is no much room, imo, for hints and stuff for such elementary and basic questions **if** one doesn't know the basic technical skills of them.

Answer (score 2):

Evaluate the eigenvalues of the matrix, call it $\;A\;$ :

$$p_A(x):=\det(xI-A)=\begin{vmatrix}x+9&-4&-4\\
8&x-3&-4\\
16&-8&x-7\end{vmatrix}=$$

$$=(x^2+6x-27)(x-7)+512-32\left[(x+9)-(x-7)-2(x-3)\right]=$$

$$=x^3-x^2-69x+189+512-32\left[-2x+22\right]=$$

$$=x^3-x^2-5x-3=(x+1)^2(x-3)$$

We know that eigenvectors belonging to different eigenvalues are linearly independent, so our matrix is diagonalizable iff the dimension of the eigenspace corresponding to the eigenvalue $\;-1\;$ is two:

$$\begin{align*}8x-4y-4z&=0\\
8x-4y-4z&=0\\
16x-8y-8z&=0\end{align*}\;\implies\;2x=y+z$$

so clearly $\;\dim E_{-1}=2\;$ and the matrix is diagonalizable.

As for a basis of eigenvectors: I'll leave that for you.